# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')

Tags: javascript, replace

Estoy presentando este error al subir el reproductor al servidor ya que en local funciona bien.

Les explico un poco, el reproductor a nivel local muestra la canción que esta reproduciendo, la que viene y la que ya sonó, pero al subir al servidor me sale el siguiente error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace') en la siguientes lineas de código pero no entiendo exactamente el por qué.
Quisiera saber is me pueden orientar en esto para terminar este proyecto y entregarlo, gracias de antemano.

```
   let song = data.currentSong.replace(/&apos;/g, '\'');
        currentSong = song.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');

        let artist = data.currentArtist.replace(/&apos;/g, '\'');
        currentArtist = artist.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
```

Comment: Tal vez alguna de las propiedades donde se utiliza ‘replace’ no existe. Lo que podrías es validar que la propiedad exista pra después usar replace

Comment: Empieza por checkear con un `console.log(data)` luego si `data` o `currentSong` no estan ok sigue paso a paso de donde vienen estos datos y asi resolveras el problema